# how to draw a map using geojson with d3.js

Tags: html, d3.js, geojson

I am trying to create a Map  from geoJson file using d3.js

```
  var canvas = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height",500)

  d3.json("WebContent/WEB-INF/data.josn", function(data){
  console.log(data)
  var group =canvas.selectAll("g")
  .data(data.features)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(7300).translate([0,1980])
  var parh = d3.geo.path.projection(projection);
  println(data)
  var areas = group.append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("class","area")
  .attr("fil","steelblue")
```

when I open the HTML page I don't get any map

Comment: You have a typo here: `var parh`

Comment: And here: `.attr("fil","steelblue")`, though this won't stop the features from drawing (they'll just be black).